# iOS QuickStart for Google Sheets API fails after converting to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, google-sheets-api

iOS QuickStart for Google Sheets API :
https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

In Xcode 8 the code works with Swift 2 but failures to get values of sheet from GTLRSheets_ValueRange.

Reproduce the problem:

1. Follow the instruction to create the project, pod, and copy-paste the code.
2. Switch on "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" in the project Build Settings - set "Yes" and select "To Current Swift Syntax..." in the menu Edit/Convert
3. Verify the application works fine.
4. Switch off "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" in the project Build Settings - set "No" and select "To Current Swift Syntax..." in the menu Edit/Convert
5. Apply conversion changes
6. Verify the application starts, authorises to the google account and calls the method "displayResultWithTicket".

Expected result:

The instruction below populate the variable "rows" with values from the result object

"let rows = result.values!"

Actual result:

The instruction below throws the error

```
"result.values"
```

However following instructions provide expected values:

```
result.range
result.majorDimension
```

I can see values within the result (in the internal structure).

Same example works in Android well.

UPD: added image with error and watching variables:

[image: Error and variable list]

The only difference between Swift 2 and 3 versions found so far in this code - field "values" is converting from Objective-C from "NSArray<NSArray *> *values" to "[[AnyObject]]?" (in Swift 2) and to "[[Any]]?" (in Swift 3): [SE-0116](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md)

[image]

UPD-2: Error points in instructions. Seems it is related to following operation. I tested bugs reported for such earlier - they are not reproduced.

```
Swift._arrayForceCast <A, B> (Swift.Array<A>) -> Swift.Array<B>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm also trying to use this Google's example and I'm getting the same error. Have you figured it out?

Comment: No, I rolled back to Swift 2 for this project. I registered a ticked at Google's tracker and posted this question in the Apple's developers forum - no feedbacks so far.

Answer (score 1):

Casting the raw JSON value seems to work around this bug

```
guard let rows = result.jsonValue(forKey: "values") as? [[String]] else
{
    // Shouldn't happen, but handle error case just in case
}

// Use rows: [[String]]
```

Comment: Works for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this blog, [Converting between Result, Optionals, and Swift 2 errors](http://radex.io/swift/error-conversions/), might help. It discussed possible ways of dealing with errors. Swift 2 introduces a new error handling model where functions can throw an error, and callers can catch them. This replaces `NSError` in bridged Objective-C classes. Based from this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/antitypical/Result), you can use `Result` whenever an operation has the possibility of failure.

Comment: Thank you. The framework looks good. I read the article you referenced, but I did not find the way to figure out this particular issue.